Can an adjustable constant-current power supply drive an audio amplifier?
I have a MeanWell HLG-240h-48A power supply that was designed to drive LEDs. I would like to use it to drive a 48V DC audio amplifier, and I was wondering if that is possible or not? It has adjust potis for voltage and current, but the current range goes from 2.5 ~ 5A, so not zero.

We cannot guess if that power supply can power your mystery amplifier with unknown specs.

Yes, possible but with some limitations:

As long as you stay below the 5A threshold to enable CC mode it will function as an ordinary 48v supply. Above that it will lower voltage to limit current.

Ah so the CC functions solely as a limiter? I was worried it might also increase voltage in order to maintain a certain amperage, which would be bad.

Update: it works.

This power supply apparently has a constant voltage mode. Most (all?) amplifier circuits use constant DC voltage supplies.
You would need to add to this power supply a bunch of transistors and resistors designed to make an amplifier circuit. This would be complicated by the fact that you have a unipolar power supply only.
Remotely possible? Yes. Practical? No.

Not practical to operate an audio amplifier from a single supply? That's the whole car audio world blown out then.

With a constant current, The only way this is likely to work is with a
class A amplifier.  most amplifiers are class D or class AB, and isn't going to work for them.
